# Removing Spaces in Excel

Tags: excel, spaces

1, there a column like this:

```
     color
     #01
     #1b
     #1b/613
     #02
     #18/613
     #04
..........
```

there is one space before the content. eg: there is a space before `#01`. When I selected the column and used left justify, but the content don't go a space to the left. How to delete the space with a batch?

2, there is a column like this.

```
     size
     160
     179
     180
      .....
```

I want to make all the line to 160 with a batch. how do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Excel use the following formula `=RIGHT(nameofcell, LEN(nameofcell)-1)` and click drag the first formula cell to generate a column that is the same as the linked cells but without the initial space.

The formula `=TRIM(nameofcell)` also removes the leading and trailing spaces of a given cell.

Once again click and drag to generate an adjacent column from your existing column, then Copy and paste your new column as value into your old column.

Either `=160` or `=nameofcellthatis160` with the click and drag will work method for your 2nd question. Note that with the second option it may adjust the formula to the nameofthecell above immediately above  it from the click and drag, but if they are all 160, then this won't matter.

Comment: Appleman1234,thank you. you're right do you know how to do the second question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

**NOTE :** A1 is Cell Name.

### Using TRIM

To remove the ***extra spaces*** that are there between two words (at start/ end)

`=TRIM(A1)`

### Using SUBSTITUTE

To remove ***all spaces*** that are there in `CELL`.

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "")`

### Here is [demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuDxo8hGuxaQdEtoejFTbE9CWmlTOVF2dnZaWDRTN1E)